# Can't move windows to lower or upper workspace

Tags: 13.10, workspaces, workspace-switcher

Ever since I upgraded to Ubuntu 13.10, I can't move workspaces to upper or lower workspace using the `Ctrl + Alt + Shift + Up/Down arrow`. I am able to move them right or left. I can even move them down/up using the Workspace switcher on the launcher.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In ubuntu 13.10 the hotkeys to move windows to workspaces up and down have been changed:

1. Move window up: <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>super</kbd>+<kbd>page up</kbd>
2. Move window down: <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>super</kbd>+<kbd>page down</kbd>

(the super key should be the "windows key" on your keyboard)

You can change the hotkeys back to what they were from system settings, keyboard, shortcuts tab, "Navigation" menu, scroll down till you find "Move window one workspace up" and "Move window one workspace down" below it.

I did this myself.

Comment: Thanks very much. PS. That seems like a really poor choice to make. Do they expect users to switch from the `arrow` keys to the `page up` / `down` keys and back, every time they want to move a window?

Comment: yeah I'm puzzled too. why do that?!

Comment: This is so jarring. It is completely unintuitive. What reasoning could that have for doing this?

Comment: I think they said it's a "regression" on "launchpad" (which is the place where bugs are reported).

Answer (score 3):

Another way to set the keys as they should have been is by performing the following commands in the terminal:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings move-to-workspace-down "['<Control><Shift><Alt>Down']"
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings move-to-workspace-up "['<Control><Shift><Alt>Up']"
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the settings in Ubuntu 22.04 are confusing and that's the root of the problem. In Keyboard | Shortcuts | Navigation, you should change the settings for *Move window one workspace up/down* ([as pointed by @Wytse](https://askubuntu.com/a/457540/639188))

[image: Ubuntu Keyboard shortcuts settings]

instead of *Move to workspace above below*

[image]

Comment: You awakened a necro-thread. The question was from 2013 - ten years ago. The OP asked about Ubuntu 13.10.

Comment: @HuHa but how could I document my solution in any other way? Asking another question just because the Ubuntu version changed isn't recommended in this case, see https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/3722/should-i-ask-the-same-question-again, because the situation is not fundamentally different